# Examples of deadlocks in APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

For a school assignment I need to simulate a deadlock in the UI of my APEX application. I know how a deadlock works and why it occurs, but I cannot figure out how someone would simulate a deadlock in an APEX application.
Keep in mind, I don't mean the SQL editor in APEX, but the actual app builder.

When would one start a transaction and how would it occur that a started transaction would run long enough for another transaction to cause a deadlock.

Hope someone could help me because I really do not know how I would simulate such a case.

Thanks.

Comment: To simulate that in apex you'd log on in 2 different sessions - either 2 different browsers or a browser + an incognito window

Comment: Yes that is how I caused it in the SQL editor. Though the professor wants to see it in the application. But how would a transaction run long enough to block another started transaction? Do you have any examples of this?

Answer (score 2):

Setup:

```
create table T as select 0 x from dual union select 1 x from dual;
```

Then on a button press, have the following PLSQL code:

```
delete from t where x = :item;
dbms_session.sleep(30);
delete from t where x = (1-:item);
```

Then fire up two APEX sessions:

- Session1: Set :item to 0 and click the button
- Session 2: Set :item to 1 and click the button